# Combine SELECT & SHOW command results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want a query like:

```
SELECT (SELECT @@version) AS VERSION,
(SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT')
```

But it failed to execute.

Result should be like.

```
VERSION  PORT
-------------
8.00     3306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below Query:

```
select @@version AS 'Version', @@PORT AS 'PORT';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.